# Referring to correctly-styled algpseudocode procedure name in document

Tags: formatting, algorithms, algorithmicx

Given an algorithm written in `algpseudocode`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Part 1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure {FooProc}{$G$}
      \State ...
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

How can I now refer to FooProc in my document (outside of the `algorithm` environment) such that it has the same typeset as in inside the `algorithm` environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the document default small caps font so `\textsc{FooProc}`

Better would be to use the package defined command `\textproc{Fooproc}` which will do the same thing, but ensure that if you customise the fonts used in the psuedo-code, the reference will use the same font.