# Pseudocode with the procedure in caption

Tags: captions, algorithms, algorithmicx

I am trying to have pseudocode similar to that in [this article](https://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.fi/&httpsredir=1&article=1128&context=csetechreports). I am currently using the algorithmicx package. My problem is that I would like to have the caption look like below:

[image]

So in caps and complete with arguments. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Below is an example. Basically I would want the "Euclid(a,b)" to be in the caption, instead of the body after **procedure**.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require Integers $a$ and $b$
\Ensure The g.c.d of $a$ and $b$
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile
\State \textbf{return} $b$
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `\textproc`, as below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\floatname{algorithm}{Procedure}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{\textproc{Euclid}$(a,b)$}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Require Integers $a$ and $b$
\Ensure The g.c.d of $a$ and $b$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}
\State $a\gets b$
\State $b\gets r$
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile
\State \textbf{return} $b$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This results in [image]

Incidentally, this is also useful when you wish to [refer to an algorithm in the text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168098/referring-to-correctly-styled-algpseudocode-procedure-name-in-document).